# How to force a layout to resize with the wizard page

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a wizard page that displays two tables and a hand full of buttons. Part of my tables scroll bars and the bottom buttons keep getting hidden and I have to expand the window when that page is reached. I am not sure if the overall layout scheme I have for this page is just set up improperly.

How can I have the layout and widgets within the layout resize along with the window?

I am using PySide2 on Python 3.7. I have tried setting the layout as a fixed size along with reading a few other threads on this but I can't seem to reproduce the same results so that the widgets fit within the window/as the window resize they scale with it.

```
class Resolution_Page(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Resolution_Page, self).__init__(parent)

        self.Resolution_Wizard_Page = QtWidgets.QWizardPage()
        self.Resolution_Wizard_Page.setObjectName("Resolution_Wizard_Page")
        self.ResolutionTable = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.ResolutionTable.setObjectName('ResolutionTable')

        self.SearchTable = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.SearchTable.setObjectName('SearchTable')
        self.SearchTable.setColumnCount(2)
        self.SearchTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Searched Field', 'Searched Value'])
        self.SearchTable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.SearchTable.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.SearchTable.setEnabled(True)
        self.SearchTable.setRowCount(0)

        self.next_resolution_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Next Resolution')
        self.next_resolution_button.setObjectName('next_resolution_button')
        self.next_resolution_button.setMaximumWidth(200)

        self.next_search_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Next Page')
        self.next_search_button.setObjectName('next_search_button')

        self.resolve_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Resolve Selection')
        self.resolve_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.resolve_button.setObjectName('resolve_button')

        self.Search = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Search')
        self.Search.setObjectName('Search')

        self.previous_search_result_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Previous Page')
        self.previous_search_result_button.setObjectName('previous_search_result_button')

        self.previous_resolution_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Previous Resolution')
        self.previous_resolution_button.setObjectName('previous_resolution_button')
        self.previous_resolution_button.setMaximumWidth(200)


        self.SearchTable.setMinimumWidth(300)

        layout = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        root_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(layout)
        central_tables = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        middle_buttons = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        bottom_buttons = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        middle_buttons.addWidget(self.previous_search_result_button)
        middle_buttons.addWidget(self.Search)
        middle_buttons.addWidget(self.next_search_button)

        central_tables.addWidget(self.SearchTable, stretch=1)
        central_tables.addLayout(middle_buttons)
        central_tables.addWidget(self.ResolutionTable, stretch=1)

        bottom_buttons.addWidget(self.previous_resolution_button)
        bottom_buttons.addWidget(self.resolve_button)
        bottom_buttons.addWidget(self.next_resolution_button)
        bottom_buttons.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)

        root_layout.addLayout(central_tables)
        root_layout.addLayout(bottom_buttons)
        layout.setFixedSize(1200,600)
```

Comment: I would just remove `layout`  and make root_layout a layout of the `Resolution_Page` object itself, i.e. `root_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parent your top widget to a main layout and prevent using a fixed size for main widget

1. Create a main layout and parent your widget to it:

```py
main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
#layout = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
layout = QtWidgets.QWidget()
main_layout.addWidget(layout)
```

2. remove this line:

```
layout.setFixedSize(1200,600)
```